# How to remove sub attribute of style

Tags: html, css

How to remove sub attribute of style. I want to remove only `display:none;` attribute of style from below code.

```
<div class="ui-state-default ui-jqgrid-hdiv" style="width: 1085px; display: none; visibility: visible; ">
```

Comment: Define two class for show-hide, and use jquery to add or remove this class. Or directly use, jquery show-hide methods.

Comment: refer to http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Comment: How you want to remove it? With CSS? or with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following can remove the `display` subattribute of element's `style` attribute in Javascript+jQuery:

```js
$('div.ui-state-default.ui-jqgrid-hdiv').each(function () {
    var st = this.getAttribute('style').split(';').map(function (a) {
        return a.toLowerCase().indexOf('display')>-1 ? '':a;
    }).join(';');
    this.setAttribute('style', st);
    // alert('TEST: display property == '+ $(this).css('display')
    // + ', style attribute == ' + $(this).attr('style'));
});
```

[test](http://jsfiddle.net/vzfre/2/)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to removing it, you can override it in your style sheet with

```
display: block !important;
```

If that code is inserted via JS, though, it might be better to remove it from the JS in the first place if you really don't want it there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.ui-state-default').css('display', 'block');
```